# Ajax chat - login issue

Tags: php, mysql, chat

On my *Ajax Chat* script I have got this warning:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
boolean given in /home/mychat/public_html/c/listChats.php on line 7
```

Line 7:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

listChats.php:

```
<?php 
$chats = "";

include_once("scripts/connect_db.php");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM chatBox order by id DESC LIMIT 20
) TMP ORDER BY tmp.id ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $chat = $row['chatBody'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $chats = '<p><span id="un">' . $username . ':</span> ' . $chat . '</p>';
    echo "$chats";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Charles My problem was to the point.

Comment: There are [**three hundred fifteen potential duplicates**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given%22) containing the error message you have provided.  Every last one of them has the same core issue.  The query failed and returned a bool.  You need to add error checking to your code, and you need to fix the underlying SQL error.  Hover over the downvote arrow.  One of the reasons suggested there is "this question does not show any research effort," and it doesn't.

Comment: Now I know why people don't come on here your -point system is crazy

Comment: @Charles Well if you say so and the reason I added this was because I was lost and needed help.

Comment: So whats the deal with the points system - / + drop in points get ban

Comment: Good questions get upvoted.  Bad questions get downvoted.  Don't take it personally.  You might not have gotten the help you wanted, but you did get this help, at least: **always search for your error message first**.  ***Always***.

Comment: @Charles I never take things personal site got rules, but thank's for the advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: @SteveFenton sorry bro its not a possible duplicate of mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select. Because my code is different same problem different help problem. Plus problem was taken care of by the help of Harry.

Comment: It is the same issue. Bad SQL syntax causes the issue. The answers to that question show you how to get the error message from MySQL to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I know that its kool bro Happy Holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong

Try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *,(

    SELECT * FROM chatBox order by id DESC LIMIT 20

) as data FROM TMP ORDER BY tmp.id ASC");
```

Updated query

```
select *,(select username from chatBox where id=".$_SESSION['userid'].") from chatBody where user_id=".$_SESSION['userid']
```

Comment: Still same issue thanks for the help

Comment: I think first you have check your db connection is establish properly or not

Comment: I used this code `$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());` and got this warning: `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'amljrx10'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/amljrx10/public_html/c/listChats.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/amljrx10/public_html/c/listChats.php on line 3
Error in query: . Access denied for user 'amljrx10'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: It indicates that amljrx10 has a password, but you are not supplying it.so give this error.

Comment: are you talking about the database password.

Comment: Ya you have must apply password when connect the database.

Comment: Yes I did the chat Box is showing and when you write and submit it; it shows it in the database but not in the box.

Comment: Means after sumbit the page data save successfully in database but not display in textbox

Comment: yes you are right "but not display in textbox"

Comment: Ok then you have write code like this in your textbox. <input type="textbox value=<?php echo $_POST['textbox_name']; ?> />

Comment: nope here's the link  [ChatBox site](http://amljr.x10.mx/c/index.php)

Comment: Your link is not working

Comment: did you click on the "ChatBox Site"

Comment: Ya its give error message Sorry, you must be logged in to chat

Comment: sorry about that forgot .. Here [ChatBox Site](http://amljr.x10.mx/c/login.php) email demo@demochat.com pass demo

Comment: I have see your code.You have blank text box in post_chat function.See it

Comment: I does not want link of your js file.I have already seen it.See in last line of function post_chat() you have blank chat text box in this function.

Comment: Remove or comment this line document.getElementById("chat").value = ""; from function

Comment: I comment it out but still warning

Comment: Can you post code of listChats.php page so I will solve your problem easily.

Comment: Have you update your code as per my answer?

Comment: Yes but still same problem

Comment: Ok tell me which detail you want to fetch from chatbox table

Comment: I just want it to show the username and text

Comment: I took out `,( SELECT * FROM chatBox order by id DESC LIMIT 20
) as data FROM TMP ORDER BY tmp.id ASC` and left this `"SELECT * FROM chatBox"`

Comment: Template meta-programming (TMP)

Comment: Query is wrong please tell me in which table you have stored username.If you want to display text of login user in div.then you have write a different query not this.

Comment: I have a table call "chatBox" with username in it and chatBody that store's the text

Comment: Ok Have you manage login user id in session or other way?

Comment: Ok try this query "select *,(select username from chatBox where id=".$_SESSION['userid'].") from chatBody where user_id=".$_SESSION['userid'] Change session name as per your code

Comment: What about now is it working right

Comment: Well I see your username as "Chat" and your text as "Is it working correctly ?"

Comment: @AgustinLeyva please tell me your problem is solve or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong table name.

Try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *,(

    SELECT * FROM chatBox order by id DESC LIMIT 20

) as data FROM TMP ORDER BY TMP.id ASC");
```

If your table is `TMP` then use `TMP.id` if it is `tmp` then use `tmp.id`